# Is this true $\vec B(\vec r) = μ(\vec r)\vec H(\vec r)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In an electromagnetism exercise, I am given a cylindrical structure with variant $μ=μ(\vec r)$, and some information about $\vec J, \vec K, I$, so i calculated $\vec H(\vec r)$, for every $\vec r$. Can I find $\vec B(\vec r)$ with the following expression?
$$
\vec B(\vec r) = μ(\vec r)\vec H(\vec r)
$$
I am asking this, because I have only seen definitions of $\vec H$ and $\vec B$ involving constant $μ$.

Comment: $\mu$ would probably be a tensor in this case.

Comment: If the tensor is diagonal and proportional to de identity the expression above would hold, but it's not general

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  $\mu=\mu(\mathbf r)$ is the quantity which tells you how to calculate the $\mathbf H$ field at a point $\mathbf r$ from your knowledge of the $\mathbf B$ field at the same point, or vice-versa.  Note that $\mu(\mathbf r)$ is generically a *tensor* quantity, which reflects the fact that $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf H$ need not point in the same direction.

---

Note that this assumes that the relationship between $\mathbf H$ and $\mathbf B$ is local in both space and time.  In other words, in order to find $\mathbf B$ at a point $\mathbf r$, you don't need to take into acount the $\mathbf H$ field at other points.

This need not be the case; one could imagine a material in which the magnetization at one point depends on the magnetization in a neighborhood around it.  Such a material is called spatially dispersive.  It's also possible that the magnetization at a point at a particular *time* depends on the magnetization at that point in the past; such a material is called temporally dispersive.

Taking both factors into account, a more general constitutive relation would be

$$\mathbf B(\mathbf r,t) = \int d^3 r' \int dt' \ \mu(\mathbf r',\mathbf r, t',t)\ \mathbf H(\mathbf r',t')$$
where $\mu(\mathbf r',\mathbf r,t',t)$ is the *nonlocal magnetic permeability*, which measures the contribution to $\mathbf B$ at some position $\mathbf r$ and time $t$ due to the $\mathbf H$ at some (possibly different) point $\mathbf r'$ and time $t'$.

The statement that the medium is non-dispersive (both spatially and temporally) says that $\mathbf B$ here and now can be calculated from $\mathbf H$ here and now, and corresponds to setting

$$\mu(\mathbf r',\mathbf r,t',t) = \tilde{\mu}(\mathbf r,t) \delta(\mathbf r - \mathbf r') \delta(t-t') $$

for some *local magnetic permeability* $\tilde{\mu}(\mathbf r,t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!